# Iterator in for looping infinitely through list

Tags: c++, list, c++11, iterator

I'm using an iterator in a for loop, and for some reason it is looping infinitely. It appears to be doing what it is supposed to be doing, though, just infinitely.

Looking at other similar questions did not help me solve my issue, as I am not using splice anywhere and tried many different ways of implementing this loop (for, while, using an int for the conditional loop, using the iterator itself, iterator advance, etc). The most progress I've had was getting an invalid read instead (see below).

I double checked the code to see if I wasn't manipulating iterator pointers directly (possibly generating a situation where list.end() = list.begin()) but couldn't find anything of the sort. All I used for this specific list was find, insert and clear.

I'm iterating through a list of pairs composed of struct pointer REG and an int. This is compiled in C++11 with -Wall and -Wextra.

Modifying it with anything to control it to stop at the last item (using .size(), or checking to see if the same position of vector colors[] is already 1), results in an invalid read error.

```
int getAvailableColor(int K, std::list<std::pair<REG*, int>> adjacency)
{
   std::list<std::pair<REG*, int>>::iterator it;   
   int Ko = K;                                     
   int colors[K];                                  

   for(int i = 0; i < Ko; i++)
   {
       colors[i] = -1;
   }

   // This loop either breaks or runs forever... In some iterations
   // At this point K is as was passed as parameter
   for(auto it : adjacency)
   {
        if(it.second == 0){
            if(it.first->COLOR != -1)
            {
                colors[it.first->COLOR] = 1;
            }
        }
    }
    // At this point K is decreased

    for(int i = 0; i < Ko; i++)
    {
        if(colors[i] == -1) { return i; }
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Apparently, removing the array modification

```
colors[(*it).first->COLOR] = 1;
```

undoes the infinite loop issue (unfortunaly undoing the algorithm as well, so not a solution). Also, it seems this line is somehow decreasing the integer K.

The function call is done here:

```
    aux->COLOR = getAvailableColor(G.K, aux->ADJC);
```

Where aux is a REG* and ADJC is a list(REG*, int). The REG structure is:

```
typedef struct REG{
    int ID;
    int TYPE; // 0 - Physical, 1 - Virtual
    int COLOR;
    int CONN;
    std::list<INTERF> INTRFR;
    std::list<std::pair<REG*, int>> ADJC;

    bool operator > (const REG& reg) const { return (CONN > reg.CONN);        }
    bool operator < (const REG& reg) const { return (CONN < reg.CONN); }
    bool operator == (const REG& reg) const { return (ID == reg.ID); }
}REG;
```

INTERF typedef is std::pair(int, int), and the function that builds the list is:

```
void setAdjacency(GRAPH g)
{
    std::list<REG*>::iterator it;       
    std::list<INTERF>::iterator it2;     
    std::list<REG*>::iterator it3 ;      
    REG* aux = newReg(-1, -1, " ");
    REG* aux2;                           
    int count;

    for(it = g.LOGREG.begin(); it != g.LOGREG.end(); it++)
    {
        count = 0;
        (*it)->ADJC.clear();

        for(it2 = (*it)->INTRFR.begin(); it2 != (*it)->INTRFR.end(); it2++)
        {
            count++;
            aux2 = getRegister(g.REGISTERS, it2->first);

           (*it)->ADJC.insert((*it)->ADJC.end(), std::pair<REG*, int>(aux2, 0));
        }

        (*it)->CONN = count;
    }
}
```

When I stop the infinite loop this is the valgrind output:

```
==13369== Process terminating with default action of signal 2 (SIGINT)
==13369==    at 0x10D008: __gnu_cxx::__aligned_membuf<std::pair<REG*, int> >::_M_ptr()
==13369==    by 0x10C67B: std::_List_node<std::pair<REG*, int> >::_M_valptr()
==13369==    by 0x10BD18: std::_List_iterator<std::pair<REG*, int> >::operator*() const
==13369==    by 0x10B116: getAvailableColor(int, std::__cxx11::list<std::pair<REG*, int>, std::allocator<std::pair<REG*, int> > >)
```

And the invalid read error:

```
==13520== Invalid read of size 8
==13520==    at 0x10BFE3: std::_List_iterator<std::pair<REG*, int> >::operator++()
==13520==    by 0x10B159: getAvailableColor(int, std::__cxx11::list<std::pair<REG*, int>, std::allocator<std::pair<REG*, int> > >) 
==13520==    by 0x10AE10: runStack(GRAPH) 
==13520==    by 0x10A500: algorithm(GRAPH)
==13520==    by 0x1107AC: main 
==13520==  Address 0x10520fb40 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==13520== 
==13520== 
==13520== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV): dumping core
==13520==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x10520FB40
==13520==    at 0x10BFE3: std::_List_iterator<std::pair<REG*, int> >::operator++()
==13520==    by 0x10B159: getAvailableColor(int, std::__cxx11::list<std::pair<REG*, int>, std::allocator<std::pair<REG*, int> > >)
```

I would appreciate any help! This is my first real try at C++ and I'm sure there's much I don't understand about the structures.

**EDIT:** Using auto as was suggested seems to have at the very least stopped the infinite loop in the first test. As I did this I also noticed the value for K was changing between before the loop and after. Making a "backup" variable solved it. However, the invalid read error and the infinite loop still happen in some tests (same structure just different inputs). Updating code above accordingly.

**EDIT2 (Solved):** The infinite loop was solved substituting the array for a vector, and the invalid read error was an implementation logic issue (K was decremented at each iteration, so even though originally COLOR was only as big as K-1, with each iteration there as a bigger overflow). Thank you so much, everyone :)

Comment: i suggest you restructure the program.  adjacency list should be a separate class; each element should be a separate class; etc.  build from small components, and make sure each component and its methods work. code like this is trouble even for experienced programmers: `(*it)->ADJC.insert((*it)->ADJC.end(), std::pair<REG*, int>(aux2, 0));`

Comment: and also see this: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @jdigital I didn't want to create a new class for adjacency list since it is just a list (and I have 0 experience with C++ or C++ classes) and I wanted to take advantage of C++ STL functions. I'll work on making the code more understandable.

Comment: What value do you use for `K`? Is it at least as big as the list?

Comment: @Rotem the list is smaller than K

Comment: What I should have asked is if K is larger than the highest value of COLOR in the list?

Comment: And also what controls the lifetime of the REG pointers? Could they be dangling pointers when you iterate over them?

Comment: @Rotem The values for color go up to K-1. Checking with prints show expected values on (*it).first->COLOR

Comment: @Rotem  I ... Don't really know. It seems that C++ has some sort of automatic destructor at the end of functions, but I admit I'm not clear on how it works... I assumed this wasn't the problem because this process is iterated quite a few times and the issue only happens in the same iteration.

Comment: @latinsniper In any case, the variable length array using `K` seems like a red flag. It's not standard c++, and only supported as an extension in some compilers. I would try to see if allocating `colors` dynamically on the heap or using e.g. `std::vector<int>` gives you any different results.

Comment: @Rotem Hey! I wanna thank you so much for your attention to that miserable little variable and the tip to change structures! I wasn't aware the variable sized array was an issue, but using vector stopped the infinite loop. There was also a mistake in how I was implementing the algorithm that did the invalid access error. That was it. Thank you so much :)

Comment: Glad you got it working.

Comment: The VLA isn't supposed to be an issue. Either the compiler supports it or it doesn't, in which case a compile time error should be issued. If it does support it, it shouldn't introduce runtime UB. Either it's a compiler bug or there is more code not posted that wpuld explain the UB, or just something I'm missing in your original code.

Comment: It would be interesting to try an create a minimal reproducible example that exhibits the infinite loop issue as a separate question.

Comment: @Rotem Yeah, I looked into it, but it's a rushed code for an assignment, so unravelling it would be even harder than it already was to find the error. I assume something else in the code was causing this incompatibility, but then it is even harder to isolate what is part of the reproducible example and what isn't (and I had no time to debug it like that).

Answer (score 3):

The code concerning the iterator doesn't look especially wrong.

Make sure that you aren't accessing the array out of bounds at this instruction:
`colors[(*it).first->COLOR] = 1;`
This is the most probable cause of your problem.

However, since you aren't modifying the iterator, and don't access it outside of the loop, I would advice you to use the enhanced for loop syntax.
Instead of:
`for(it = adjacency.begin(); it != adjacency.end(); it++)`
You could easily replace with:
`for (auto it: adjacency)`
Unless you must be C++03 compatible.
This will save you from a number of stupid errors.

Comment: Oh ***** that worked... Does that mean it was actually an error with the configuration of the iterator? From what I understood of auto it simply infers the syntax of a simple loop, so it would mean the loop was in fact wrong?

Comment: EDIT: It sort of worked in the sense that it's not infinitely looping anymore, but it did cut the loop short... So I guess the auto inferred something wrong?